# How do I set Notepad++ to auto-correct to curly quotes instead of vertical quotes like in MS Word?

Tags: notepad++

The quote character by default produces the vertical quote character: "
I would like for it to instead produce curly quotes like in MS Word: “”

Auto-Complete in preferences only has an option for smart quotes convert " to "", but no option to change the actual characters used. I'd expect there to be a hotkey or auto-complete option that will yield “” in some form. I've seen replace options, but I would like for these changes to be made automatically while typing as in MSWord.